# Подключение локальных шрифтов сайта на WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, шрифты, google-fonts

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения локальных шрифтов к сайту на WordPress.
Сайт на хостинге, подключение на прямую по ссылке Google Fonts работает, но нужно локально с папки fonts на сервере подключить.

https://vip-dublikat.ru/tarusa/ - ссылка на сайт.

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  src: url("http://vip-dublikat.ru/tarusa/wp-content/themes/newtarusa/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff") format("woff"), url("http://vip-dublikat.ru/tarusa/wp-content/themes/newtarusa/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"); 
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  src: url("http://vip-dublikat.ru/tarusa/wp-content/themes/newtarusa/assets/css/Montserrat-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("http://vip-dublikat.ru/tarusa/wp-content/themes/newtarusa/assets/css/Montserrat-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"); 
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Код нужно показывать кодом, а не картинкой.

Comment: У тебя сайт на https, а фонты подключаешь по http. Учись пользоваться консолью браузера.